# Change App Landing Page

Tags: facebook, configuration

I have created a facebook app that works properly, but when it is searched for on facebook, the user is redirected to an app landing page (http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=111111111). How can I make it so that the user is redirected to the app instead (http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the window's parent location using JS. `window.top.location` If it's not in the URL that you are expecting then redirect.